# Multiple rows concatenated in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

```
id    data
1     note1
1     note2
3     note6
3     note8
```

when I select data from this table I want to get the data column values concatenated like

```
select data 
from table 
where id = 1 --(this query is just for demonstration )
```

needs to give an output like

```
note1+note2
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Note:I had tried using  COALESCE (which i got from Vishal) and it also not working .This is how my actual query now looks like

```
    declare @var1 varchar(200)

SELECT     dbo.kt_missingdataview.Varenummer, dbo.kt_missingdataview.Varenavn, dbo.kt_missingdataview.Producentvarenummer,
                          (SELECT     dbo.ETEXT.TXT1
                            WHERE      (dbo.ETEXT.ID = 1)) AS shortdesc,
                            (SELECT @var1 = COALESCE(@var1 + '+', '') +  dbo.ETEXT.TXT1 from dbo.ETEXT 
Select @var1),
                          (SELECT     dbo.ETEXT.TXT1
                            WHERE      (dbo.ETEXT.ID = 2)) AS longdesc, dbo.ETEXT.REFKEY, dbo.ETEXT.ID
FROM         dbo.kt_missingdataview INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ETEXT ON dbo.kt_missingdataview.Varenummer = dbo.ETEXT.REFKEY
WHERE     (dbo.ETEXT.ELANGUAGE = 0)
```

Comment: This question has already been asked [many, many times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+concatenate+values) for SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `FOR XML PATH` to get the result:

```
select distinct t1.id,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct '+ ' + t2.data
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.id = t2.id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') data
from yourtable t1;
```

Comment: @AKS What are the performance issues?  Do you have any indexes?  My suggestion would be to post a new question about the issues.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, you can use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
declare @var1 varchar(200)
SELECT @var1 = COALESCE(@var1 + '+', '') +  data from the_table where id = 1
Select @var1
```

Output: `note1+note2`

Comment: your query is throwing errors I will show you my full query in ext comment

Comment: You are using `join query` so please make a proper use this in your  query and I'm not able to understand your query.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a DBMS so I'm assuming Postgres:

```
select id, string_agg(data, '+')
from the_table
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, use the [GROUP_CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT id, group_concat(data)
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE ID=1
```

Comment: Sorry for that.but i am using ms sql